# SQLite Exception: no such column

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am using a SQLite database and I got this this error:
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: coin (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, age, coin, log FROM person_tb1 WHERE name = ?

I have no idea why it show me this!
I have tried it before its working fine!

Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList<Person> getPersons (){

    persons.clear();

    SQLiteDatabase dba = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = dba.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{Constants.KEY_ID, Constants.NAME, Constants.AGE , Constants.COIN , Constants.LOG},null,null,null,null,null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.NAME)));
            p.setAge(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.AGE)));
            p.setCoin(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COIN)));
            p.setLog(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.LOG)));
            p.setPersonId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ID)));

            persons.add(p);

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();
        dba.close();
    }
    return persons;
}
```

and here the select method :

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            Constants.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + Constants.NAME + " TEXT, "+
            Constants.AGE + " INT, " + Constants.COIN + " INT, " + Constants.LOG + " INT);";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

// EDIT : (OnUpgrade)

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + Constants.TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wild guess: You added the column **after** running the app once.
If so (`i have tried it before its working fine !`), just unistall and reinstall your app.

OR you can simply increment your DATABASE_VERSION constant.

**[EDIT]**

But the second method won't work, since your current `onUpgrade()` method is **buggy**.

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + Constants.TABLE_NAME);
```

Won't delete the table. And so, it won't be recreated, even.
You need to insert a **space** before the table name:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Constants.TABLE_NAME);
```

Comment: or just +1 the db version, and make sure you apply whatever migration is necessary in the onUpgrade (which usually is just a drop/create)

Comment: Yes, another way to do that :)

Comment: i have the onUpgrade in my code ^^ ! look i updated my post

Comment: `i have the onUpgrade in my code` It's simply **not enough** to have it. You must activate it by incrementing your DATABASE_VERSION constant. OR, uninstall and reinstall your app. That's how it works. ALSO, your onUpgrade contains a bug, which prevents its work: you miss a space before the table name.

Comment: thank youu so much !! u saved my life xD ! i just reinstall my app !

Comment: Exxaggerated!! :) It would be so beautiful if someone could save a life with a small programming hint!